# Embeddings of symplectic group into the orthogonal group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $\mathfrak{sp}$ denote the complex symplectic Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{so}$ the complex orthogonal one. Do we have an embedding
$$
\mathfrak{sp}_{2n-2} \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{so}_{2n}?
$$
In other words, we are asking if we have an embedding of type $C_{n-1}$ into type $D_n$.

I suspect not, but cannot think of an argument.

Comment: If $n=1$ or $n=2$, then the answer is Yes.

Comment: If $n>2$, then the answer is No, Indeed, the minimal dimension of a nontrivial irreducible representaition $V$ of  $\mathfrak{h}:=\mathfrak{sp}_{2n-2}$ is $2n-2$. Thus any nontrivial $2n$-dimensional  representation of $\mathfrak{h}$ is isomorphic to $V\oplus {\rm Triv}\oplus {\rm Triv}$.

Comment: It remains to observe that the only $\mathfrak h$-invariant symmetric bilinear form on $V$ is $0$.  Since ${\rm dim\,}V>n$, any  $\mathfrak h$-invariant symmetric bilinear form on  $V\oplus {\rm Triv}\oplus {\rm Triv}$ is degenerate, which completes the proof.